# Binding dropdown to column values

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a lightswitch 2012 app that is getting data from an OData Service that is returning a single table of data. I have created two parameters within a query, and then added them to a screen via new data items. The first parameter is connected to a choice list, and if the application is run, the value passed from the choice list filters the values on the screen.

The problem I'm having is creating another dropdown that contains the values of one of the columns in the table that is being returns from the OData service.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a way for users to have a way to scroll through a list of values, and when the value is selected, it will filter the screen. If I pass in the value via a text box, it will filter the grid. The problem is there could be hundreds of possible values.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

thanks,

Jason

Here is the entity

[image: The Entity]

Here is the query

[image: The query]

The Grid Screen

[image: Grid Screen]

The application Running

[image: Grid Running]

Answer (score 1):

Just like you used "*Add New Data Item*" to add your original parametrised query to the screen, you can also use it to add another query (based on the table that has the values you want to dislay/filter by).

Once you add it to the screen, drag the query from the left-hand side to the screen control tree. This will give you a dropdown box (called an *AutoCompleteBox* in LS). Then all you need to do is bind the original query's second paranmeter to the *SelectedItem* of the second query.

You seem to understand most of the concepts, but maybe this video from Beth Massi will help with the final parts.

[Creating a Custom Search Screen in Visual Studio LightSwitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/11/09/creating-a-custom-search-screen-in-visual-studio-lightswitch.aspx)

Comment: I have tried as suggested, but I am still having trouble changing the type on the textbox for the Item Number. I have uploaded the solution to git hub https://github.com/jwstl/SYPTest. I am thinking this could possibly be due to the fact that the Projects table that I am referencing has two primary keys.

Comment: LightSwitch doesn't "like" entities that don't have an avalaible integer PK. Sometimes, you can get away with it, depending on what you're doing, so it's possible that this is what's causing your problem. What you're trying to do is usually very simple.