# how to implement a generic period selection control in LightSwitch/C#

Tags: vba, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am in the process of finding a heir for a few good ole client side Access\VBA applications. LightSwitch is really impressive and I've decided to give it a serious try. Among the things I want to reproduce is a generic menu that allows the automated selection of periods and subsequent filtering of data on dates. As most of our data screen do include dates, this kind of filtering tool is a must: it makes standard period selection easy and it's then possible to switch between screens keeping the same selection period (and it's of course more efficient than standard date pickers).

It has been proven to be very efficient and is one of our users favorites.

The VBA\existing menu is made out of 6 combined controls, with:

1. a first list box, with standard periods current\previous\next
   month\trimester\year etc
2. a minus and a plus controls, that add
   automatically 1 unit to the from\to date (the unit depends on the
   value in the list box: if 'month' is selected, clicking on '+' will
   add 1 month to the from\to dates)
3. a 'from' and a 'to' date boxes, where I can see the selected dates and\or manually update their value
4. a 'refresh' button

[image: generic period menu]

So I am not expecting here a complete solution but, as i am definitely new to LightSwitch, and still a C# beginner, I am waiting for some ideas or proposals. I think I'll have to create a custom control, but I must admit that I don't know where to start. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Lightswitch has it's own way of doing things and it's own language for things that may not be obvious for a beginner. I'm going to use standard Lightswitch names for things. If you don't understand what something is, just ask and I'll elaborate.

You can implement this control using a combination of 6 standard controls as you did before.

The first would be a [Choice List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff852048.aspx), a static list of values that presents as an AutoCompleteBox (i.e. a drop down). You would then edit the `_Changed` method of the Local Property used to create the Choice List. Inside that method, you would create a switch/case to set a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type variable to the desired period.

The plus and minus would just be normal buttons. You would edit the `_Execute` methods of each to add/subtract the TimeSpan to/from the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type Local Properties that represent the From and To dates. You will need to take special care here and probably use some intermediate variables as [DateTime values are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737595/adding-a-timespan-to-a-given-datetime).

The From and To dates can just be Local Properties of the type Date or DateTime as mentioned above. This will create a standard Silverlight Date Picker control which is quite nice.

[image: date picker]

The refresh would again just be a button that sets the Parameters of the [Filter Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256728.aspx) that you would use to display the Grid Control holding your data. That sequence of events is well represented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359107/binding-dropdown-to-column-values) only you would be binding the Date properties instead of an AutoCompleteBox (i.e. drop down).

Hopefully that made sense and those links should point you in the right direction. I would also recommend [Beth Massi's video series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/12/01/beginning-lightswitch-getting-started.aspx?Redirected=truehttps://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/12/01/beginning-lightswitch-getting-started.aspx?Redirected=true) to get a good handle on the basic mechanics of a Lightswitch app. And you might want to consider making the application's code base in VB.NET. All the above still applies but the syntax may be slightly more familiar if you're coming from a VBA background.

Comment: Thanks for this generous and detailled answer. I began to work on your instructions and I'll keep you informed.